# What does 'Share Project' Subversive do?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, ide, subversive

In the Eclipse Subversive Plug In, What does `Share Project` do? Is It Committing the code to a repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It enables version control on your project. You can choose which version control system to use after that and configure it. SVN in your case.

Comment: will it affect the repository when initial sharing?

Comment: It doesn't affect the repository. You still have to explicitly commit in order to push to the repository.